# Bash or KSH concatenate multiple delimited files with headers

Tags: bash, file, concatenation

I have dozens of files coming in, all are in a .dat format and contain headers.

What I want to do is concatenate all the files into a single file called merged-date.dat located in the same directory. This is easy enough, but the problem comes in that all the files have a header row. So for any file beyond the first, I want to eliminate that header row (aka the first row) during the concat process so I don't have multiple records containing the header. Anyone have any ideas? Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file without the first line for example with `tail -n+2 file`. So you could copy the first file as it is and merge all the remaining in a loop.

```
cp file1.dat concat.dat
for file in remaining files; do
    tail -n+2 $file >> concat.dat
done
```

The loop header of the above code is pseudo code.

If `remaining files` is hard to calculate compared to all files, alternatively you just add the header to the new file and then merge all other files.

```
head -n1 file1.dat > concat.dat
for file in /folder/to/files/*; do
    tail -n+2 $file >> concat.dat
done
```